# PHP / MYSQL Retry wehn duplicate happens

Tags: php, mysql

```
$new_acct_id = 'ACC'.strtoupper( substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,5) );


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `accounts` (id, market_unit_id, account_type_id, is_inactive,inactive_notes,is_special,dealer_id, is_premium)
VALUES ('".$new_acct_id."', '".$mu_id."', '".$atype['0']."', '".$is_inactive."','','','', '".$is_premium."')") or die("load2 -" . mysql_error());
```

load2 -Duplicate entry 'ACC96E38' for key 'PRIMARY'

is there anyway I can have it generate another number if the first creates an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
do{
    $error='';
    $new_acct_id = 'ACC'.strtoupper( substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,5) );
    $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `accounts` (id, market_unit_id, account_type_id, is_inactive,inactive_notes,is_special,dealer_id, is_premium)
    VALUES ('".$new_acct_id."', '".$mu_id."', '".$atype['0']."', '".$is_inactive."','','','', '".$is_premium."')");
    if(!$res)$error=mysql_error();
}while(!$res && strpos($error,'Duplicate entry')!==false);
if(!$res)die($error);
```